# SwiftData crash in TestFlight build when using sortBy nested @Model object

Tags: swift, swift-data

Here are my SwiftData models

```
@Model
class ClosedDealModelContainer {
    var closedDeal: ClosedDealModel

    init(closedDeal: ClosedDealModel) {
        self.closedDeal = closedDeal
    }
}

@Model
public class ClosedDealModel: Hashable {

    public enum DealType: Codable {
        case long
        case short
    }

    public let id: String
    public let userId: String
    public var buy: BuyModel
    public var sell: SellModel
    public var type: DealType
    public var symbol: String
    public var currency: String

    public init(
        id: String,
        buy: BuyModel,
        sell: SellModel,
        type: DealType,
        symbol: String,
        userId: String,
        currency: String
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.buy = buy
        self.sell = sell
        self.type = type
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.userId = userId
        self.currency = currency
    }
}

@Model
public class BuyModel {
    public let fee: Double
    public let date: Date
    public let price: Double
    public let count: Double

    public init(fee: Double, date: Date, price: Double, count: Double) {
        self.fee = fee
        self.date = date
        self.price = price
        self.count = count
    }
}

@Model
public class SellModel: Equatable {
    public let fee: Double
    public let date: Date
    public let price: Double
    public let count: Double

    public init(fee: Double, date: Date, price: Double, count: Double) {
        self.fee = fee
        self.date = date
        self.price = price
        self.count = count
    }
}
```

And here is code that fetches deals SORTING by nested @Model object property

```
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<ClosedDealModelContainer>(
            predicate: #Predicate { container in
                container.closedDeal.userId == userId
            },
            sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.closedDeal.sell.date)]
        )
        let items = try modelContext?.fetch(descriptor)
```

In debug and release version it works perfectly, but in TestFlight build it crashes with this line:
static PersistentModel.keyPathToString(keypath:)

Also I tried to deploy build with sorting by ClosedDealModel.id and it works as expected so the problem is in nested object but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

P.S. I'm using SwiftData outside of SwiftUI

Comment: Do you have any more info about the crash, what is the actual error message, stack trace...?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't see actually any useful info in crash log